# Manipulating variables

Tags: abstract-algebra

How do I get $p^{a+a'}q^{b+b'}z^{c+c'}$ from $p^{a+a'} q^{b'+ac'+b} z^{c+c'}$ with $pqp^{-1}q^{-1} = z$,  $zp=pz$, and $zq=qz$. I'm not sure how to deal with the $q^{ac'}$ term.

Comment: can you clarify the term $pqp-1q-1= z$?

Comment: Wow, Um I didn't write that!Let me edit what I wrote...it seems some one changed it. for the relations, it is p to the negative power and q to the negative power.

Comment: I think it has to do with the last relation, with every pq I must get a zpq, correct?

Comment: $z$ is something called the *commutator* of $p$ and $q$. That may help.

Comment: I commuted and moved the z around and found nothing that would lead me to the answer

Comment: i found the answer but the commuter comment kept sounding in my head, thanks.